# python function return not working

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I have a recursive traversal function to go through a JSON object and return the information that I want. The problem is that it's not returning anything. I know that the recursion is working properly because I modified to function to print out the input at each step and it was printing out the expected results - including the final step.

```
def wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki):
    if type(wiki)==dict:
        if 'definitions' in wiki.keys():
             wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki['definitions'])
        elif 'text' in wiki.keys():                       
             wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki['text'])
        else:
             pass
     elif type(wiki)==list:
        wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki[0])
    else:
        return wiki
```

Comment: There's no `return` statement anywhere in the `if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a return after each function call, the returns don't bubble up automatically.

```
def wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki):
    if type(wiki)==dict:
        if 'definitions' in wiki.keys():
             return wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki['definitions'])
        elif 'text' in wiki.keys():                       
             return wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki['text'])
        else:
             pass
    elif type(wiki)==list:
        return wikipedia_JSON_traversal(wiki[0])
    else:
        return wiki
```

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick! I spent several hours trying to debug this.